# ML.NET AUC is not defined when there is no positive class in the data Arg_ParamName_Name

Tags: c#, machine-learning, ml.net

I want to use Random Forest method in my project.
I have this error trying to use EvaluateNonCalibrated:

> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: „AUC is not defined when there is
> no positive class in the data Arg_ParamName_Name”

```cs
var testSetTransform = _trainedModel.Transform(_dataSplit.TestSet);
return MlContext.BinaryClassification.EvaluateNonCalibrated(testSetTransform);
```

Here you have models:

```cs
public class MLCategoryPrediciton
{
    public bool PredictedLabel { get; set; }
}
```

```cs
public class MLFinancialChange
{
    [LoadColumn(1)]
    public bool Label { get; set; }
    [LoadColumn(2)]
    public float Value { get; set; }

    [LoadColumn(3)]
    public float CategoryId { get; set; }
}
```

And way i preparing data:

```cs
public async Task FitAsync()
{
    var list = await fcRepository.FindAllAsync();
    var output = new List<MLFinancialChange>();
    foreach(var item in list)
    {
        var x = new MLFinancialChange
        {
            Value = item.Value,
            CategoryId = item.Category.Id,
        };
        output.Add(x);
    }

    IDataView data = MlContext.Data.LoadFromEnumerable<MLFinancialChange>(output);
    DataOperationsCatalog.TrainTestData dataSplit = MlContext.Data.TrainTestSplit(data);
    _dataSplit = dataSplit;
    var dpp = BuildDataProcessingPipeline();
    var tp = dpp.Append(_model);

    _trainedModel = tp.Fit(_dataSplit.TrainSet);
}
```

```cs
private EstimatorChain<NormalizingTransformer> BuildDataProcessingPipeline()
{
    var dataProcessPipeline = MlContext.Transforms.Concatenate("Features",
                        nameof(MLFinancialChange.Value),
                        nameof(MLFinancialChange.CategoryId)
                        ) 
       .Append(MlContext.Transforms.NormalizeMinMax("Features", "Features"))
       .AppendCacheCheckpoint(MlContext);

    return dataProcessPipeline;
}
```

Thanks for help

I just want that to work and i tried to find solution in the internet. Unfortunatelly i spent a lot of time trying fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this problem before, and I think it was because the model wasn't predicting any positive cases. You can try inspecting the predictions and just make sure it's not predicting everything as negative.